# System.Net.WebException command unrecognized

Tags: vb.net, upload, ftp, webexception

I am trying to upload picture to ftp. I can connect using filezilla or explorer. But when I use vb.net code I get error: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Syntax error, command unrecognized. Please help. I am going mad. Code I am using:

`Public Sub upload2ftp(ByVal _FileName As String, ByVal _UploadPath As String, ByVal _FTPUser As String, ByVal _FTPPass As String)
        Try
            Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(_UploadPath), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
            request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(_FTPUser, _FTPPass)
            request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
            request.UsePassive = False
            request.KeepAlive = False
            Dim file() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_FileName)
            Dim strz As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            strz.Write(file, 0, file.Length)
            strz.Close()
            strz.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try`

Answer (score 0):

Problem was Kaspersky. Turned it off and upload went good.